# PHPSpreadsheet - ignore rows with cells containing certain values

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using PHPSpreadsheet to read a large sheet (11000 rows) but wish to ignore rows that have a cell with a certain value. These rows can be ignored when reading the file and then using toArray() reducing my array to far less rows. PHPSpreadsheet is unable to successfully complete on so many rows so I need to reduce this somehow.

Comment: I don't know much about PHPSpreadsheet, but I think you either read the whole file, or nothing, it cannot ignore rows when loading a file. What error message do you get? Out of memory?

Comment: yeah - the site just crashes... I have tried reading the whole file and saving it locally before continuing but to no avail.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. PHPSpreadsheet can filter on reading see: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/